# Spark streaming (python) with local files

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, pyspark

Is there a way scan the local file system for changes in a specific folder, like you can with HDFS ([GitHub example](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/python/streaming/hdfs_wordcount.py))? Running it using a regular path or a URI with `hdfs://` seems to work, but using a URI with `file://` in front of it doesn't.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext

XML_PATH = "file:///home/user/in"
APP_NAME = "StreamingTest"
BATCH_DURATION = 1 # in seconds

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sc = SparkContext("local[*]", appName=APP_NAME)
    ssc = StreamingContext(sc, BATCH_DURATION)
    lines = ssc.textFileStream(XML_PATH).pprint()
    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Oddly enough this seems to work on specific files. When `XML_PATH` is changed to `"file:///home/user/in/test.txt"` the output is the same if the file is there.

```
-------------------------------------------
Time: 2016-01-14 16:04:34
-------------------------------------------

-------------------------------------------
Time: 2016-01-14 16:04:35
-------------------------------------------
```

but when the file gets deleted during the streaming, the app starts throwing exceptions

`16/01/14 16:04:37 WARN FileInputDStream: Error finding new files
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/home/user/in/test.txt does not exist`

which I assume should indicate that it can read from the local directory.

I tried changing the `XML_PATH` to `/tmp/in` which is a directory on HDFS and uploading the same file while running the stream, and that seemed to work

```
-------------------------------------------
Time: 2016-01-14 16:13:12
-------------------------------------------

-------------------------------------------
Time: 2016-01-14 16:13:13
-------------------------------------------
The Project Gutenberg EBook of Ulysses, by James Joyce
subscribe to our email newsletter to hear about new eBooks.

-------------------------------------------
Time: 2016-01-14 16:13:14
-------------------------------------------
```